# bash script rm cannot delete folder created by php mkdir

Tags: bash, rm, sh

I cannot delete folder created by php mkdir

```
for I in `echo $*`
do
    find $I -type f -name "sess_*" -exec rm -f {} \;
    find $I -type f -name "*.bak" -exec rm -f {} \;
    find $I -type f -name "Thumbs.db" -exec rm -f {} \;
    find $I -type f -name "error.log" -exec sh -c 'echo -n > "{}"' -f {} \;
    find $I -type f -path "*/cache/*" -name "*.*" -exec rm -f {} \;
    **find $I -path "*/uploads/*" -exec rm -rdf {} \;**
done
done
```

I want to delete under /uploads/ all files and folders please help me thanks...

Comment: also asked on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9897049/7552

Comment: Does the script runner have write permissions on `*/uploads/*`?

Comment: **Do NOT crosspost** same question on different sites, unless it asked explicitly. You *have answer* on SO